# Incorrect results, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following simple LINQ to SQL statement:

```
string strUserID = Eval("whoInsert").ToString();

insLusHmoobDataContext userDataContext = new insLusHmoobDataContext();

var userName = from usr in userDataContext.Users
               where usr.UserId.Equals(strUserID)       
               select usr.UserName;

return userName.ToString();
```

Instead of showing me the `UserName` from the `aspnet_Users` table, it showed me the SQL select statement. Any idea?

Comment: As a general hint: If you have to add a `ToString()` somewhere to make it compile and you don't know why, then this is a strong indication that you are missing an important step. In your case, it's executing the query (as the answers explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userName = (from usr in userDataContext.Users where usr.UserId.Equals(strUserID)     
select usr.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
```

That's assuming there's going to be a single user for that ID, else you could use `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add .Single().ToString();

Otherwise you haven't actually executed the query - you ate reporting the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

userName is a LINQ to SQL expression tree which evaluates to the SQL query when converted to a string.

You probably want userName.First().ToString() instead;

That way the query is executed and you get the first value returned.
You may want to use FirstOrDefault() and check for null values to be sure of not crashing :)